# How do i access a filemaker script with javascript in Web Viewer using Apple Mapkit?

Tags: javascript, mapkit, filemaker

I have Filemaker 18 with a Web Viewer using Apple Maps. When I move a pin on the map I want to send the coordinates to a filemaker script that writes to 2 fields. The problem is I can not trigger the script. The database is hosted on a FM Server 18. I have tried these 3 approaches but I am not even able to run a simple "Hello" script. The database name is WEBMAP.fmp12 . Here is how I have tried to run the script. I get no response:

1)
var theURL = "fmp://$/" & Get ( FileName ) & "?script=Hello&param=" + lat +"|"+ long;
window.location = theURL;
2)
var theURL ="fmnet://ip_address_of_server/WEBMAP.fmp12?script=Hello&param=" + lat +"|"+ long;
window.location = theURL;
3)
var theURL = "window.location = "fmp://$/WEBMAP.fmp12?script=Hello&param=" + lat +"|"+ long;
window.location = theURL;

In fact I notice that when I have anything after showing a popup (then I want to run the script) the map is blank whatever I add like "alert("hello").

Here is my js file in Filemaker 18:

```
var message = document.getElementById("message");
var center = new mapkit.Coordinate(x,y); // 

mapkit.init({
    authorizationCallback: done => {
        done(
            "<<$$JWT.TOKEN>>"
        );
    }
});    //alert("<<$$JWT.TOKEN>>");

        var map = new mapkit.Map("map", { 
            showsScale: mapkit.FeatureVisibility.Visible,
            center: center
        });

        var marker = new mapkit.MarkerAnnotation(map.center, {
            draggable: true,
            selected: true,
            title: "Dra meg og slipp!"
        });
        marker.addEventListener("drag-start", function(event) {
            // No need to show "Drag me" message once user has dragged
            // event.target.title = "";
            // Hide message
            message.style.display = "none";
        });
        marker.addEventListener("drag-end", function() {
          // center map to marker when moved
            map.setCenterAnimated(marker.coordinate); 
          // hide message after seconds
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                message.style.display = "none";
            }, 3550);

          // message to show after move
            var lat     = marker.coordinate.latitude;
            var long    = marker.coordinate.longitude;
            var message = document.getElementById('message');
            message.innerHTML = "<p>Vi har lagret posisjonen</p>Latitude: " + lat + " <br />Longitude: " + long;
            message.style.display = "block";

//alert("Hello"); ** this alert works!! **
//var test = ‘Hello World!’; alert(test); ** this line gives me a blank map just adding a "var statement" **
var theURL = "fmp://$/" & Get ( FileName ) & "?script=Testaccess&param=" + lat +"|"+ long;  

        window.location = theURL;
// alert(theURL) here gives me blank map
        }); // END drag-end
        map.addAnnotation(marker); 


        var lat     = marker.coordinate.latitude;
        var long    = marker.coordinate.longitude;
        var borchbio = new mapkit.CoordinateRegion(
            new mapkit.Coordinate(lat,long),
            new mapkit.CoordinateSpan(0.002, 0.002)
        );

        map.region = mymap;
        map.mapType = "hybrid";map.setCenterAnimated(new mapkit.Coordinate(x,y), true);
```

Comment: *"I am not even able to run a simple "Hello" script.'* Why don't you start with that and show us how you tried to do that and what happened as a result. On the face of it, it seems like a privilege issue - see: https://help.claris.com/en/pro-help/index.html#page/FMP_Help%2Fextended-privileges.html%23ww1029256.

Comment: Thanks! I think security was the issue. I turned on access to launch URL from script (fmurlscript) in Extended Priveleges. At the same time I corrected the URL so now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to set "fmurlscript" rights. Thanks to @michael.hor257k and more detailed help from @paul_tuckey at the Claris Community. His answer [here](https://community.claris.com/en/s/question/0D50H00008127nJSAQ/how-do-i-access-a-filemaker-script-with-javascript-in-web-viewer).

File-->Manage-->Security-->Advanced Settings-->Extended Privileges,
Select fmurlscript
Click Edit,
Add the Privilege set that is aligned to your Account Name to the selected fmurlscript

With this code I am able to run a FM script from javascript. Here is the code that triggers the script. Notice that when my database is "WEBMAP.fmp12" I only use "WEBMAP" as the name. I am sending the lat and long to the script that does stuff with it (converts it and writes to the post). The "fmp18://" targets specific version 18.

```
  var theURL = "fmp18://$/WEBMAP?script=My_FM_Script_Name&param=" + lat +"|"+ long;
  window.location = theURL;
```